# Add a unique id to every y of a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am training an auto-encoder using MNIST and tensorflow.

```
(ds_train_original, ds_test_original), ds_info = tfds.load(
    "mnist",
    split=["train", "test"],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

batch_size = 2014
def normalize_img(image, label):
    """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0, label
```

I would like to have my `x` be the image and my `y` to be a tuple with the same image associated with a unique index value (a int/float). The reason is that I want to pass that id to my loss function. I would like to not manually iterate and create a new Dataset but if that's the only solution'll go with it.

I have tried multiple things such as using the map method with a global var:

```
lab = -1
def add_label(x, _):
    global lab
    lab += 1
    return (x, (x, [lab]))

ds_train_original = ds_train_original.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train_original.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits["train"].num_examples)
# replace labels by image itself and unique id for decoder/encoder
ds_train = ds_train.map(add_label)
```

However, this return 0 as the index for all inputs instead of a unique value.

I have also tried to manually add a label by enumerating the dataset, but it is taking forever that way.

Is there an efficient way to modify a TensorFlow dataset when the function applied to it is not uniform on the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I would do in this case would be to just use the `ref()` method of the target tensors. Every tensor already has a unique identifier and this method allows you to access it.

You can try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

(ds_train_original, ds_test_original), ds_info = tfds.load(
    "mnist",
    split=["train", "test"],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

# save the references to your tensors
ids = np.array([y.ref() for _, y in ds_train_original])

# you can check that they are all unique
print(ids.shape, np.unique(ids).shape)

# find the 42th tensor using the deref()
t = ids[42].deref()
print(t)

# use np.where to find the index of a tensor reference
np.where( ids == t.ref())[0]
```

Comment: I'll try that, it seems to be perfect for my use case. Thx. I'll accept the answer as soon as I tested it!

Comment: Actually on further inspection it doesn't seem to work because the ref changes between epoch (?). I feel like I need to start with an element created with ref(): doing 1) ref = i.ref() (where i is the first element of ds_train) 2) ref == i .ref() -> returns false

Comment: I'll accept the answer because I believe the solution works but ref() is behaving weirdly when using tensorflow_datasets somewhere.